# Javascript box duplicate itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, duplicates

Hey I have made a game with a box that moves around. I need help with when I press ENTER I want the box to duplicate its shape and stay in the position where I pressed ENTER. I also want it so the box cant move outside of the screens width and height.

```css
#box {
  background-color: #FF002F;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  background-color: #BDBFBF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="box"></div>


  <script>
    document.addEventListener("keydown", test);
    var boxS = document.querySelector("#box");
    var radius = boxS.clientWidth / 2;
    console.log(radius);

    var boxY = (window.innerHeight / 2) - radius;
    var boxX = (window.innerWidth / 2) - radius;
    boxS.style.top = boxY + "px";
    boxS.style.left = boxX + "px";




    function test(event) {
      console.log(event.keyCode);
      var keyCode = event.keyCode;

      var boksSize = 35;
      /*var xMin = 0;
      var xMax = screenWidth - boxRadius;
      var yMin = 0;
      var yMax = screenHeigth - boxRadius; */

      if (keyCode === 87 || keyCode === 38 && boxY > boksSize) {
        boxY -= 35;
        boxS.style.top = boxY + "px";
      } else if (keyCode === 68 || keyCode === 39) {
        boxX += 35;
        boxS.style.left = boxX + "px";
      } else if (keyCode === 37 || keyCode === 65) {
        boxX -= 35;
        boxS.style.left = boxX + "px";
      } else if (keyCode === 40 || keyCode === 83) {
        boxY += 35;
        boxS.style.top = boxY + "px";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service, post what you tried.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Please add a clear problem statement (see [ask]). FYI, problem statement !== "what I want".

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
Try to experiment with parameters. in JSFIDDLE, I had to somewhere add come coefficient to not be able to go behind borders ... so, it is more like guidline, but you have to enhance the method to be able to work on every monitor by yourself.

https://jsfiddle.net/12914t27/

```
    <body>

  <div id="box"></div>


  <script>

    var shadows =0;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", test);
    var boxS = document.querySelector("#box");
    var radius = boxS.clientWidth / 2;
    console.log(radius);

    var boxY = (window.innerHeight / 2) - radius;
    var boxX = (window.innerWidth / 2) - radius;
    boxS.style.top = boxY + "px";
    boxS.style.left = boxX + "px";




    function test(event) {
      console.log(event.keyCode);
      var keyCode = event.keyCode;

      var boksSize = 35;
      /*var xMin = 0;
      var xMax = screenWidth - boxRadius;
      var yMin = 0;
      var yMax = screenHeigth - boxRadius; */

var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

      if (keyCode === 87 || keyCode === 38 && boxY > boksSize) {
       if (!(boxY-document.getElementById('box').clientHeight <=0)){
          boxY -= 35;
          boxS.style.top = boxY + "px";}

      } else if (keyCode === 68 || keyCode === 39) {
      if (!(boxX+document.getElementById('box').clientWidth*2 >=window.innerWidth)){
         boxX += 35;
        boxS.style.left = boxX + "px";}



      } else if (keyCode === 37 || keyCode === 65) {
      if (!(boxX-document.getElementById('box').clientWidth <=0)){
          boxX -= 35;
        boxS.style.left = boxX + "px";}



      } else if (keyCode === 40 || keyCode === 83) {
        if (!(boxY+document.getElementById('box').clientHeight*2 >=window.innerHeight)){

            boxY += 35;
        boxS.style.top = boxY + "px";
         }

      }

      else if (keyCode === 13) {
// Your existing code unmodified...
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'shadow'+shadows;
iDiv.className = 'shadowbox';
iDiv.style.top = boxS.style.top;
iDiv.style.left = boxS.style.left;
iDiv.style.left = boxS.style.left;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
shadows++;

      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#box {
  background-color: #FF002F;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
}
.shadowbox {
  background-color: #555555;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  background-color: #BDBFBF;
}
```

//EDIT I have forgotten one thing: Add `z-index:1` for shadowbox and `z-index:2` for box so the box is over the created boxes and not behind them, so you can always see the original box